# Why do I need to give the whole key when trying to delete a public keypair?

Tags: debian, apt

I am sharing a specific key so it's simple and easy to show -

```
$ apt-key list

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-jessie-security-automatic.gpg
-------------------------------------------------------------------
pub   rsa4096 2014-11-21 [SC] [expires: 2022-11-19]
      D211 6914 1CEC D440 F2EB  8DDA 9D6D 8F6B C857 C906
uid           [ unknown] Debian Security Archive Automatic Signing Key (8/jessie) <ftpmaster@debian.org>

$ sudo apt-key del D21169141CECD440F2EB8DDA9D6D8F6BC857C906
[sudo] password for shirish: 
OK
```

Again running the apt-key list tells me that the key is no longer there.

I tried it with some different keys if using the short keycode for e.g. if just using the first 8 alphanumeric keys it works, but found it doesn't.

apt-key is part of apt

```
$ dpkg -S /usr/bin/apt-key
apt: /usr/bin/apt-key


 $ apt-cache policy apt
    apt:
      Installed: 1.8.0
      Candidate: 1.8.0
      Version table:
     *** 1.8.0 990
            990 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 Packages
            500 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian unstable/main amd64 Packages
            100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

I looked at the Debian [BTS](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/pkgreport.cgi?repeatmerged=no&src=apt) but couldn't find a bug and dunno whether it's a bug or it's a wishlist feature that I need to file. Can anybody comment ?

Answer (score 0):

The first part of the question is itself incorrect. It seems it is not the first 8 alphanumeric letters but the last 8 alphanumeric letters so in my case it would be **C857 C906** which if I would want to delete, that would be the short key id.

The other part of the issue is that you could have two keys have the short key id but not the long key id so it makes sense to use the whole key to delete a certain public/private keypair fromt the keyring or key list rather than using short keys as your may delete keys which you did not want to delete in the first place. This was made a feature of apt.